# InvalidAudienceForResource exception with Exchange.Callback.V2 token in Outlook for iOS

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, intune

I have an Outlook add-in with ReadWriteMailbox permissions that calls Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}) to get what is generally a valid auth token:

```
{
    "oid": "oid",
    "puid": "puid",
    "smtp": "xxx",
    "upn": "xxx",
    "clientappid": "3382ce5c-ed22-4195-aeca-c5b67384706f",
    "ver": "Exchange.Callback.V2",
    "appid": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
    "deploymentid": "https://outlook.office365.com/",
    "tid": "tid",
    "acr": "1",
    "appidacr": "0",
    "scp": "Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite",
    "nbf": 1588259750,
    "exp": 1588260650,
    "iss": "https://outlook.office365.com/",
    "aud": "a_vanity_url",
    "happ": "API"
}
```

In Outlook for iOS, I am now seeing this exception in a handful of environments:

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "omitted_for_redundancy",
    "responseJSON": {
        "error": {
            "code": "InvalidAudienceForResource",
            "message": "The audience claim value is invalid for current resource. 
                        Audience claim is 'a_vanity_url', 
                        request url is 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/a_message_id' 
                        and resource type is 'Exchange'.",
            "innerError": {
                "requestId": "requestId",
                "date": "2020-04-30T15:15:51"
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 401,
    "statusText": "Unauthorized"
}
```

The common theme seems to be whenever an MDM/MAM is configured (usually Intune), and it's happening across all managed devices on the tenant, and continues to fail until a device is unregistered and its Outlook accounts are removed and re-added.

Is there something I can do differently when I request an auth token to prevent this failure? Or is there a device management setting that Outlook for iOS requires to run add-ins?

Comment: What are the API calls being made using the token?

Comment: It's failing on my first call to GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages//{message_id}.

The application later calls that same endpoint with filters (expand attachments, select smtp headers), as well as 
POST messages/{message_id}/createForward, PATCH messages/{message_id}, POST messages/{message_id}/move, POST messages/{message_id}/attachments, DELETE messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}, POST messages/{message_id}/send, and POST me/sendmail.

Comment: @DustinBrungart were you able to find out what was causing this issue ? any fix for such an error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround here is just to use the vanity domain returned in the JWT's `audience` claim as the API URL base instead of the value returned by `Office.context.mailbox.restUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting and it seems like it is not an addin issue. Can you please raise a support case with Intune by going to [Link](https://endpoint.microsoft.com/), navigate to "Troubleshooting + Support". The corresponding team will address the issue.